# Смысл от дружественных функций в C++

Tags: ооп, классы, c++

Какой смысл несут дружественные функции для класса и дружественные классы для класса:

```
class B;

// class A definition
class A {
  int n1, n2;

  friend void print_fields(A a);  // практический смысл?
  friend class B; // практический смысл?

public:
  set_fields(n_1,n_2) {
    n1 = n_1;
    n2 = n_2;
  }
};

void print_fields(A a) {
  cout << a.n1 << " " << a.n2 << endl;
}
```

Зачем так делать:

```
   friend void print_fields(A a);
```

Если данный метод и так является фактически публичным членом класса( раз он дружественный, то доступен отовчюду ) и, соответственно, тмеет прямой доступ к начинки класса?

Это тоже не совсем понятно:

```
  friend class B;
```

Ведь класс А можно "запротектить" (protected) и все будет ок. **Объясните, пожалуйста.**

Comment: >Если данный метод и так является фактически публичным членом класса

нет, он не метод и не является публичным членом класса. Это внешняя функция. А вот зачем ей понадобился доступ к кишкам класса - отдельный вопрос. Например, таким образом приходится реализовывать перегрузку операторов между разными классами. Т.е., скажем, чтобы можно было сделать не только CComplex + CComplex, а и CComplex + CFloat, и CFloat + CComplex.

Comment: Во-вторых, public/protected/private имеют очень загрубленную область действия. Т.е. public - доступно ВСЕМ, protected - доступно наследникам, а private - доступно ТОЛЬКО членам-функциям класса. friend позволяет точечно предоставлять доступ, не выпячивая в public или переменные, или setter'ы для них.

Comment: Также дружба позволяет дополнять функционал библиотечных классов, код которых нежелателен для изменения.

Comment: @gecube , спасибо за объяснения! Пока на практике я чаще всего встречаю перегрузку оператора Output-потока << через дружественный метод.

Comment: ДА, и кстати, по поводу ваших утверждений. То есть если я захочу объявить некую дружественную функцию для класса, описанного где-то вглуби како-либо библиотеки, писанной не мной, то я должен буду лезть в тот класс в той библиотеке и описывать friend-функцию там? Или можно это сделать как-то вне класса?

Comment: Если используете написанную кем-то библиотеку, то, в общем случае, в вашем распоряжении только интерфейс, предоставляемый классами данной библиотеки, в том числе только те френд-функции, которые предусмотрены разработчиком этой библиотеки.

Answer (score 2):

Иногда действительно возникает необходимость из вне иметь доступ к закрытым полям данных твоего класса. В этом случае без друзей не обойтись.

Вот пример - ты написал класс описывающий игрового юнита. Этот класс содержит внутреннее представление m_HP и открытый интерфейс *Injure* - нанести урон, *Heal* - лечить и *IsAlive* - проверка, жив ли юнит.

```
class Unit
{
public:
    friend void TestUnit();

    Unit(unsigned maxHP)
    : m_maxHP(maxHP)
    , m_HP(maxHP) {};

    void Injure(unsigned val) {
        m_HP -= val;
        if( m_HP < 0 ) { m_HP = 0; }
    };

    void Heal(unsigned val) {
        m_HP += val;
        if( m_HP > m_maxHP ) { m_HP = m_maxHP; }
    }

    bool IsAlive() const { return m_HP > 0; }

private:
    unsigned m_maxHP;
    int m_HP;
};
```

Ты решаешь обернуть функционал класса юнит тестами, что бы быть уверенным в том, что функции *void Injure(unsigned val)* и *void Heal(unsigned val)* работают корректно:

```
void TestUnit()
{
    Unit unit(100);
    unit.Injure(10);
    assert(unit.m_HP == 90); // check private data field
    unit.Heal(20);
    assert(unit.m_HP == 100); // check private data field
}

int main()
{
    TestUnit();
}
```

Как видишь, написание теста было бы невозможно без обращения к внутреннему представлению класса. Именно для этого мы объявили функцию *void TestUnit()* дружественной к классу *Unit*

**Upd:**

Еще один пример использования дружественных функций при проектировании собственного класса и обеспечения его функциональности. Ниже приведен очень простой пользовательский класс оборачивающий целое число. Для помещения экземпляров данного класса в выходной поток самым естественным образом необходимо определить функцию operator<< не являющуюся экземпляром класса

```
#include <iostream>

class WrappedInt
{
public:
    explicit WrappedInt(int val)
    : m_value(val)
    {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const WrappedInt& val);

private:
    int m_value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const WrappedInt& val)
{
    os << val.m_value;
    return os;
}
```

а для того, что бы эта функция имела доступ к закрытым полям класса, таким как m_value, мы и делаем ее дружественной по отношению к классу WrappedInt.